# What's the best way to add a directory to the path env variable when running a CMake-based project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to set up code for a Qt application in Visual Studio using CMake.

I can get it building if I set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in CMakeSettings.json, but I can't find a way to run the application from Visual Studio without copying Qt DLLs into the build directory with the exe. I'd like to add the QT binaries directory to the PATH environment variable but do so in some way that doesn't involve touching CMakeLists.txt.

Below is what I am currently doing. I'd like to get rid of the `if(win32)...` which as far as I can tell does not even work when trying to launch a release build from Visual Studio because `VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT` just applies to debug builds.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(calculator VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_executable(calculator
    button.cpp
    calculator.cpp
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(calculator PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)

set_target_properties(calculator PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON
    MACOSX_BUNDLE ON
)

if(WIN32)
    set_target_properties(calculator 
        PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=%PATH%;C:/libraries/Qt/6.2.3/msvc2019_64/bin;"
    )
endif()
```

A [Microsoft blog post says](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/set-environment-variables-for-debug-launch-and-tools-with-cmake-and-open-folder/) that you can do this via `launch.vs.json` for the executable but I couldn't get this to work. This was the `launch.vs.json` I tried:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "out\\build\\x64-Debug\\calculator.exe",
      "projectTarget": "",
      "name": "calculator.exe",
      "env": {
        "PATH": "C:\\libraries\\Qt\\6.2.3\\msvc2019_64\\bin;%PATH%"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "_I'd like to get rid of the if(win32)... which as far as I can tell does not even work when trying to launch a release build from Visual Studio because VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT just applies to debug builds._" Nope! That's just wrong. It will apply to all the generated build configs. So... are you still against that approach? Because I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: well it's not working for my release configuration but idk. I mean I'm against this way because it seems like you shouldn't have stuff in CMakeLists that is not only specific to one platform but specific to my local machine i.e. where I have Qt installed

Comment: 1) "_you shouldn't have stuff in CMakeLists that is not only specific to one platform_" - I personally think it's fine as long as it's guarded correctly with `if()` commands / [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#platform). 2) "_specific to my local machine_" - okay but can you not just use [`<PackageName>_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) (Qt6_DIR)? Or does the value of that variable not include the `msvc2019_64` part? Try printing that variable with `message("Qt6_DIR: ${Qt6_DIR}")`

Comment: "_well it's not working for my release configuration but idk_" - weird. I did a test with Visual Studio 17 2022 and put a string with "beep-boop" in there, then did a grep/ripgrep for "beep-boop" and it was in all four of my generated build configs. How did you do your check?

Comment: actually I got launch.vs.json working. If you go through the debug menu rather than right-clicking on the exe in solution explorer, it generates a launch.vs.json file that is the same as the one in the question except that "project" is set to"CMakeLists.txt" and "projectTarget" is set to "calculator.exe" and it works.

Comment: if you have the time, would you mind answering my question in my previous comment? You can also write up the answer you found.

Comment: I think using a variable like you sare saying probably would work, but I still could not get that way to work for Release builds. I checked that it didnt work in Release by trying to run in Release and seeing that it didn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using the `launch.vs.json` file. The trick is how you get to this file.

In the question I am modifying the `launch.vs.json` I got by right-clicking on the built .exe in the solution explorer in file view mode and selecting "debug settings" or something like that. This gives you JSON that has "project" set to the executable's path and "project target" set to the null string, which does not actually work, as far I can tell.

However, if you go through the main menu system, `Debug / Debug and Launch Settings`, you will get `launch.vs.json` with "project" set to "CMakeLists.txt" and "project target" set to the executable. If you then add to the PATH env variable as below:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "calculator.exe",
      "name": "calculator.exe",
      "env": {
        "PATH": "%PATH%;C:\\libraries\\Qt\\6.2.3\\msvc2019_64\\bin"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can launch from Visual Studio in Debug and Release.

The trick here however is that `Debug / Debug and Launch Settings` will be grayed out until you select a real startup item. By "real" startup item I mean do not select your `main.cpp` file through the Solution Explorer akin to how you would select a startup project if you were using .sln-based project. Selecting a file as the startup item actually works but it's buggy -- it messes up the using `launch.vs.json`. What you are supposed to do is select a startup item from the combo box that is to the right of the configuration combo box. This combo box will only be populated after you have successfully built something. Once you select a startup item from the combo box the menu item for launch settings will be enabled.

Comment: nice. thanks for writing this up. but what I don't get about this is that you were saying that you didn't want a solution where you hardcoded a machine-specific path into your config.

Comment: launch.vs.json is local to my machine. It doesn't get checked in to source control. It lives in the .vs directory which is in my .gitignore file. this means if someone else wanted to contribute to this codebase, they need to handle getting the Qt DLLs in their PATH themselves, but they may already have it in their PATH or they may be on Linux where it might not be an issue, etc. The idea is that i deem how you get it running launched from VS the VS user's problem, not the platform independent build system's problem.

Comment: It doesn't work for me (VS 2022). Even with the correct syntax `"env": { "PATH": "C:\\mypath;${env.PATH}" }`. Frustrating...